# Which type does an event generated by a "submit" event listener have?

Tags: typescript, types

Given the following code, which type would `event` have?

```
form.addEventListener("submit", event: ??? => {
    // code
});
```

Specifically, I am trying to access the DOM nodes from the event object via `Event.target[<index>]`. I am aware that I could get them via `document.getElementById()` separately, but I would prefer to do it without this.

Comment: How about you test it with `any` and output the event to the console for further analysis?

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ that, I have been doing, though I'm not entirely sure what I should be looking for to find the answer to this. I have code that successfully does what I want by first casting the element as `unknown`, and then `HTMLFormElement[]`, but that's not exactly a pretty solution. It would be better to know its type.

Comment: I believe it's the DOM `Event` type. Your console output should show you the type of the object anyway.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ yes, that is what it indeed seems to be in TypeScript, however, said type seems to have invalid properties for events generated by a "submit" event listener (doesn't let me treat Event.target (has the type EventTarget) as an array, which I can do at runtime). With that said, however, your answer seems correct, but not the one I was hoping for. :')